Conditional random selection in Python?
I am brand new to Python and I am trying to make a fictional character generator. I would like to randomly select the character's general disposition from a list of three options, then randomly specify further what kind of disposition they have depending on the previous selection.
dispositionList = ["Neutral Disposition", "Positive Disposition", "Negative Disposition"]
disposition = (random.choices(dispositionList, weights=(50, 40, 20)))
print(disposition)

if disposition == "Negative Disposition":
    dispspecList = ["Narcissist", "Complainer", "Grumpy", "Angry", "Liar", "Depressed"]
    dispspec = (random.choices(dispspecList))
    print(dispspec)

I was expecting this to work like so:

If the condition is "Negative Disposition", then
it will randomly select from the negative disposition list. For example, "Depressed".
It then prints "Depressed".
It does NOT print from the positive list etc.

When I go to run this code, it ignores my if statement.

random.choices() returns a list so will never equal a string. Perhaps random.choices(dispositionList, weights=(50, 40, 20))[0] (the first item in that list) would work for now.

Related A weighted version of random.choice

Debugging would help you find the problem yourself. Please share the results of your debugging session. Launch the debugger, set breakpoints, inspect variables, ...

Another option is to write: if "Negative Disposition" in disposition:

@quamrana 's solution is working for me, thanks!
